What type of load cell is used to measure swingweight of a tennis racquet
This is the pic of the loaded cell from a Babolat racquet diagnostic machine to measure swingweight of a racquet in kg/cm2. There are three wires connected to the cell and a 4 pin jumper connector to the main board. There is
No load cell amplifier in the machine. (https://i.sstatic.net/7oKWc8We.jpg)
I am assuming it’s a rotational load cell or a button load cell (https://i.sstatic.net/eAalOt2v.jpg)
